# Angularjs, nvd3, and real time line chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js

I have to find a way to workaround this bug https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/335
What I want to do is to find a way to do the transformation after I put a new data inside the array of the samples that are shown in the chart. My code is this:

```
    var windowDimension = 60; //seconds since we update every second
    $scope.summary = {};
    $scope.ddd = [
                {
                    "key": "Series 1",
                     "values": []
                }
            ];

    var summaryResource = summaryService.getSummaryResource();

    summaryResource.get(function(data) {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.summary = data;
        }, 500);
    });
    /**/

    $scope.onTimeout = function(){

        summaryResource.get(function(data) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.summary = data;
            }, 500);
        });
        mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);

        $scope.ddd[0].values.push([$scope.summary.timeAsLong, $scope.summary.totalThroughput]);

        if($scope.ddd[0].values.length > windowDimension)
            $scope.ddd[0].values.shift();
    };


    var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);
```

This code is inside the controller of the page and the page has a "nvd3-line-chart" directive that accept "ddd" as the source of the data.
Everything works, as in the bug is explained but I want to avoid the y transformation and do the call to transform the graph between the `values.push` and the `values.shift` calls.

The transform call is this

```
path.attr("d", line).attr("transform", null).transition()
.ease("linear").attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ")");
```

but I don't know how to call it inside the controller

Comment: I scope often does not have access to the DOM element (by design). 

I would suggest creating a directive that takes care of this for you. Bind "ddd" from the model into the directive's scope, watch it, and do the appropriate D3 calls whilst doing your update logic. 

Or poor man's version, generate a unqiue ID and bind to it in the DOM. then use a selector to locate the element.